Which orbital type overlaps easiest
Do  higher energy orbital overlap more readily in a reaction and more often compared to lower energy orbitals and hybridized orbitals. So when a heavy element that forms covalent bonds like antimony or Gold (Which can form covalent bonds) reacts, will it overlap / form covalent bond more readily or easier compared to hybridized orbitals like sp3 in carbon or like p orbital in halogens.

I have enough knowledge on chemistry to explain it using basic HSAB theory. If anyone has a more complete answer, feel free to correct me.
The idea that higher energy orbitals overlap more readily than lower energy orbitals is unfortunately not necessarily true. This misconception usually arrives when looking at $S_N2$ mechanisms where students are told that higher energy orbitals make better nucleophiles and thus reactions occur more readily. Therefore, nucleophiles like $\ce{HS-}$ react more readily than nucleophiles like $\ce{HO-}$. However, the true picture is more complex when it comes to bonding. A good counterexample would be to analyse covalent bond strength down the group for halogens where $\ce{Cl-Cl}$ is a stronger bond than $\ce{Br-Br}$ as a result of poorer overlap between higher energy orbitals. The idea that higher energy $\equiv$ better overlap is a false one and what belies it is a subtle control between overlap, energy differences and electron repulsion.
A more clearer picture could be elucidated from a simple bonding picture between atoms. It could be shown from perturbation theory that the energy for an atomic orbital could roughly be given as $$\hat{H}=\hat{H}_0+\hat{H}_1$$ where the zeroth order perturbation $\hat{H}_0$ roughly corresponds to the electrostatic attraction between the two atoms and the first order perturbation $\hat{H}_1$ roughly corresponds to the overlap between two orbitals (or the constructive interference, causing an increase in electron density between atoms).
To put this in simple english, $\hat{H}_0$ represents the pure ionic attraction due to differences in charge while $\hat{H}_1$ represents the covalent contribution to a bond. In other words, the stabilisation of a bond is an interplay between the two factors. This is the first factor that makes the pure picture of orbital energies determining overlap determining bond strength to fail. This is also the reason why for carbonyl reactions, species with high energy orbitals like $\ce{HS-}$ are not necessarily better nucleophiles since the factor that is more important is the $\hat{H}_0$ term and thus, reaction favours nucleophiles which are more negatively charged.
When it comes to $\hat{H}_1$ contribution, it is shown that the stabilisation is in fact roughly proportional to $\frac{S}{\Delta E^2}$ where $S$ is the degree of overlap between orbitals and $\Delta E$ is the energy differences between orbitals. It could be seen from here that it is not just an overlap but the differences in energy that contribute to stability. This is the second factor that makes the picture of orbital energies determining overlap determining bond strength to fail. However, it is the $\Delta E$ factor that mainly determines why $S_N2$ reacts favour species with higher energy orbitals, since it decreases the energy with the even higher empty orbital on the carbon.
Even when considering $S$ purely, higher energy orbitals do not necessarily lead to better overlap. For instance, for $p$ and $s$ block elements, down the group, as the orbitals have higher energies, the orbitals in fact become more diffuse and less able to form stronger bonds. Therefore, homonuclear diatomics for $p$-block elements usually show a decrease in bond strengths down the group like the halogens. Conversely, $d$ block elements, down the group, the orbitals also become more diffuse but become more able to form stronger bonds. Therefore, there is in fact an increase in bond strength for d-block elements.
There are much more subtleties when it comes to bond theory and simply looking at bond energies is not sufficient.

Is it possible for an element to readily bond but readily form a weak bond. Like for example, although F - F bonds are extremely weak, is it possibly for when F atoms react, they would easily react but they form a weak bond

And also how does overlapping with p and s orbital compare to overlapping with hybridized orbitals

By readily form a weak bond i mean Can elements overlap their orbitals to form weak orbital interaction. As an example Can antimony readily react with Cl despite weak orbital overlap between p orbitals compared to C or F which has hybridized and lower energy p orbital interactions

I think the thing is SbCl5 does exist. I think it is hard to comment on whether overlapping with p and s versus overlapping with hybridised orbitals are better because it has been shown that the simple 1/4 s character 3/4 p character for let’s say an $sp^3$ orbital is simply not true even for simple molecules like $\ce{CH4}$

Is it possible for a chemical to easily form weak orbital interaction or would you say that almost al the time, chemicals will more easily form a strong orbital interaction.
